# Cursor positioning in MARS

Tags: assembly, mips, cursor-position, mars-simulator

Please I am trying to create a MIPS program that can monitor the degree/position of a cursor. Here is my code presently. It runs successfully, but I don't see anything.

```
.text
    li $s7,100 #load a = 100
main:
    
for:
    move $a0,$v0
    move $a1,$v1
    j for2
    
for2:
    move $a2,$t6
    move $a3,$a0
    move $t2,$a1
    li $s5,10
    move $a2,$s6
    li $k1, 21
    beq $s1,$s2, foo3
    jal foo3
    beq $s3,$t5, foo1
    jal foo1
    j for2

foo1:
    addi $sp,$sp,1
    j for
    
foo3:
    li $s4, 20
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure MARS doesn't have any cursor-position system calls to move the text cursor around in the output window.  Its toy system call API is too primitive.  https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html.  And AFAIK, there's not memory-mapped-IO way to manipulate the cursor either.  I don't know about the bitmapped graphics output mode, whether it supports any mouse cursor stuff.

Comment: What if instead of using syscall we use bits. Bit 0 = left, bit 1= right etc?

Answer (score 0):

First I assumed that:

1. The status register is in $a7
2. X and Y co-ordinate is in memory
3. For left-click, I assigned 1 to $a0, 1 to $a1

status reg
X
Y

andi $a6, $a7, 00000001

beq $a6,ZERO,SKL #If the first bit is zero, go to the left function below.

addi $a0,ZERO,1 #ELSE run this line
SKL: #FOR THE LEFT click.

```
 andi $a6, $a7, 00000010

 beq $a6, ZERO, SKM #GOES to check for middle if it is zero 

 addi $a1, ZERO, 1 #Else it is in the middle
```

SKM:
andi $a6, $a7, 00000100

```
beq $a6, ZERO, SKR #Skips the next line to check for right click

addi $a1, ZERO, 1 #Else it is in the Middle
```

SKR:
andi $a6, $a7, 10000000

```
beq $a6, ZERO, SKXY #Skips the next line to X&Y co-ordinate

addi $a1, ZERO, 1 #Else it is in RightClick
```

SKXY:   jr rs